# Lesotho third-party car insurance

Tags: insurance, lesotho

Has anyone any experience or knowledge regarding third-party car insurance in Lesotho? We are traveling to Lesotho for 4 days, and it seems like our current car insurance company (Santam) does not cover third-party car insurance in Lesotho, and that we need to get that ourselves.

Does anyone have any information regarding this?

Comment: Have you asked Santam? You surely can't be the first to come up against this?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold to clarify exactly what they're after.